# Binary tree nodes with index

Tags: c++, indexing, binary-tree

I need to make optimized search for vector using binary search tree.
for example I have `vector<int>` numbers where I store {5,4,3,2,1}
then I copy those 1,2,3,4,5 to binary tree and need to return index where it is stored in vector.
For example, search(4) will have to return 1 because numbers[1] = 4
I've tried giving nodes index but they don't match in the end
Is there a better solution or how do I correctly give index to tree nodes

```
struct node {
    int data;
    int index;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
    node* insert(int x, node* t) {
    if(t == NULL) {
        t = new node;
        t->data = x;
        t->index = 0;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(x < t->data) {
        t->left = insert(x, t->left);
        t->index += 1;
    }

    else if(x > t->data) {
        t->right = insert(x, t->right);
        t->index += 0;
    }
    return t;
}

node* find(node* t, int x)  {
    if(t == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if(x < t->data) {
        return find(t->left, x);
    }
    else if(x > t->data) {
        return find(t->right, x);
    }

    else
        return t;
}

int main() {
    BST t;
    vector<int> storage;
    for ( int i =0; i< 10; i++) {
        storage.push_back(rand()%100 +1);
        t.insert(storage[i]);
    }
    t.display();
    t.search(15);
}
```

Comment: forgot to add another part of code -     int search(int x)
    {
        root = find(root, x);
        cout << root->index << " " << root->data <<endl;
        return root->index;
    }

Comment: You haven't shown any code for your BST, and the functions you do show are never directly used in your code.

Comment: other BST functions are not really related to it they're like remove elements, find min/max or print. I could add them but i can't find how to edit this post. and the functions are used - t.insert(storage[i]) and t.search(15)  which is in my comment above

Comment: That's not the issue. You are showing a function `node* insert(int x, node* t)` for example, but in `main` you never use it. Instead you use `BST::insert` that only takes and `int`. Are we supposed to guess what the function in `main` is doing?

Comment: There is an `edit` button just below your question on the left side.

Comment: struct node is inside class BST. I think it should answer your question

Comment: Please read about [mcve].

Comment: When you insert a value, simply pass in the index of the value into the `insert` function. When you construct your node, you will set the value of the `index` field to the value you have passed in.

Comment: Thanks Mike for answering my question idk how i haven't actually thought about that...

Comment: Use an `std::map` to map the value of an element to its index.

Answer (score 0):

```
    node* insert(int x, node* t, int index)
{
    if(t == NULL)
    {
        t = new node;
        t->data = x;
        t->index = index;
        t->left = t->right = NULL;
    }
    else if(x < t->data)
    {
        t->left = insert(x, t->left, index);

    }

    else if(x > t->data)
    {
        t->right = insert(x, t->right, index);

    }

    return t;
}
```